# How can i find all invertible elements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

An operation $*$ is defined on the set $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$, ie. the set containing all pairs of integers by:

$$
(u,v) * (x,y)=(u+x,v \cdot y)
$$

What are all the invertible elements of the monoid $(\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}, *)$?

And if $(\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}, *)$ is not a group what is an equation that does not have a solution?

Comment: To speak of monoid, $*$ has to be associatiative.
But
$$ ((1,2)*(2,3))*(3,4)=(3,6)*(3,4)=(9,24)$$ 
$$ (1,2)*((2,3)*(3,4))=(1,2)*(5,12)=(3,24)$$ Do you perhaps mean $(u,v)*(x,y)=(u+x,v\cdot y)$?

Comment: It is a bit odd that $x$ does not appear at all in the right hand side of the definion; Maybe there is a typo?

Comment: Yes thats what i mean , and i just edited my post

Answer (score 1):

This is the direct product of two monoids: $\Bbb Z$ with addition and $\Bbb Z$ with multiplication. The neutral element therefore is $(0,1)$ and $(u,v)$ is invertible iff $u$ is invertible additively and $v$ is invertible multiplicatively. That is, $u$ is arbitrary and $v\in\pm 1$.

For example $(0,2)*(x,y)=(0,1)$ does not have a solution.

Comment: i'm a little confused how did you find the invertible elements? Can you please explain me in more details